# Wiring back-to-back ethernet sockets

Tags: cable, cat6

I need to wire two cat 6 sockets, each in a different room, so that a switch connected to each, via patch cables, can communicate.

What cabling standard should I use:

1) T-568A at both ends?
2) T-568A at one end and T-568B at the other?
3) Some completely different standard and which?

The diagram shows the requirement more clearly.

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhc21.png)

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, you need a cross-connected cable to connect two switches. That means you should use T-568A at one end and T-568B at the other.

On the other hand, to avoid confusion, wall cabling should use "straight" connections (the same standard at both ends). Then you would use a "straight" patch chord to connect one of the switches to the wall socket and a "cross" patch chord to connect the other switch to the wall socket.

Having said that, your gigabit switches likely support "auto-MDX", which means they are able to detect the wiring automatically. In that case, you can use the same standard (either T-568A or T-568B, your choice) at both ends of your wall connection and "straight" patch chords for both switches.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the speedy and helpful reply.